# chrome.tabs.onUpdated event not fires at first time visit of web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created an extension for Google Chrome. The general logic of background.js executes, when chrome.tabs.onUpdated event fires.
Everything works fine, but I noticed, that onUpdated event is not fired sometimes.
For example, if I go on the site directly or from google search - in most cases first visit not invoke onUpdated event.. But if I refresh a page - then it always work.
Why?
I was thinking, that first time visit onCreated event works instead of onUpdated. But I checked this suggestion and it is not so..
How to fix it?

Here is a part of code:

```
    // Listen for tab update
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        console.log(changeInfo);
        imageCounter = 0;
        imageTotalCounter = 0;
        partnerFound = false;
        partnerInfo = false;
        if (changeInfo.status === "complete") { // waiting for a moment when page loading will be completed
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = tab.url;
            console.log(tab);
            var hostname = a.hostname; // get a hostname of current tab url
            chrome.storage.local.get(function(obj) {
...
})
```

Comment: Can you please include your code in your question?

Comment: You can see the code now

Comment: Well. I guess it is because preloaded webpage. google search preload the webpage top ranked.  AFAIK, this issue is reported already.